# According to North, Wallis, and Weingast (NWW), which states/societies have successfully made the transition to open access?

Tags: economic-history, development

Weingast ([2016](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03585522.2016.1233134)) writes:

> The NWW framework redefines the process of economic and political development as the transition from a limited access order to an open access order. The transition is a difficult process, and NWW argue that only two or two and a half dozen states have successfully completed it.

Earlier, NWW ([2009](https://books.google.com/books?id=e48I6-Xgt8UC&pg=PR18&dq=%22Perhaps%2025%20countries%20and%2015%20percent%20of%20the%20world%E2%80%99s%20population%20live%20in%20open%20access%20societies%20today%22)) had written:

> Perhaps 25 countries and 15 percent of the world’s population live in open access societies today

Have NWW ever explicitly stated what specifically these "two or two and a half dozen states" or "[p]erhaps 25 countries" are?

In NWW (2009), they have three subchapters (6.5, 6.6, and 6.7) specifically discussing the transition to open access in Britain, France, and the US. So these are three. What are the other 20+ states that in their opinion have also successfully made this transition?

Answer (score 0):

In NWW (2006) they write "In the twentieth century Taiwan, South Korea, Ireland, and Spain appear to have made very rapid transitions [to open access]."
Most of the 37 countries in the OECD would seem to have made the transition, with exceptions being Columbia, Hungary, Mexico, and Turkey. Several Balkan and the Baltic countries may not make the grade either. Perhaps using a combination of Pritchett's (2021) 'stock' version of Polity IV and the WB Ease of Doing Business data would provide a useful measure of open access to political and economic organizations. (Although the latter seems to be increasingly discredited).